# Changing a lxc container hostname

Tags: containers, rename, lxc

Is there any way to rename a lxc container hostname with a command sent *inside* the container's command line? I know that you can do something like `sudo mv /var/lib/lxc/oldname /var/lib/lxc/newname` and then rename hostname and paths in config with (`sudo vim /var/lib/lxc/newname/config`).

But could I do it without leaving the container's console and then typing in the main console?

Comment: just running the hostname command inside the container does not work? or setting the hostname with the usual config files?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on distribution. On Debian should be enough:

- edit `/etc/hostname` file, set to e.g. `host.example.com`
- add primary IP address (probably `eth0` interface) to `/etc/hosts`:

  `192.168.1.5 host.example.com`

Then check with `hostname -f`. On physical node you should be able to update hostname without reboot using `sysctl kernel.hostname=host.example.com`. Inside LXC container `/sys` might be mounted as read-only, so restart might be needed.